# Snowflake - given a start and end date column, break out each month and count number of days for the month into separate rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below table (`dates_table`), that has rows that look like the below, for example with `start_date` = '2022-01-25' and `end_date` = '2022-02-04'.

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-02-04 |
| 2018-08-31 | 2018-10-05 |

and I'm trying to create a new table from the above and add another column `days_count`, that takes the start_date 1/25, sees how many days are in that month (so 7 in first row because 1/25, 1/26, 1/27, 1/28, 1/29, 1/30, 1/31) and 4 in the next row because 4 days for 2/1 - 2/4:

| month | start_date | end_date | days_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-02-04 | 7 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-02-04 | 4 |
| 2018-08-01 | 2018-08-31 | 2018-10-05 | 1 |
| 2018-09-01 | 2018-08-31 | 2018-10-05 | 30 |
| 2018-10-01 | 2018-08-31 | 2018-10-05 | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one CTE to provide the data, and a couple of pre-conditioning CTE's

```
WITH data_table(start_date, end_date) as (
    SELECT * from values
        ('2022-01-25'::date, '2022-02-04'::date),
        ('2018-08-31'::date, '2018-10-05'::date)
), large_range as (
    SELECT row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn
    FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000))
), pre_condition as (
    SELECT 
        start_date
        ,end_date
        ,datediff('month', start_date, end_date) as m
    FROM data_table
)
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', dateadd('month', r.rn, d.start_date)) as month
    ,d.start_date
    ,d.end_date
    ,datediff('day', greatest(d.start_date, month), least(d.end_date, dateadd('day', -1, dateadd('month', 1, month))))+1 as days_count
FROM pre_condition as d
JOIN large_range as r ON r.rn <= d.m
ORDER BY d.start_date, month;
```

gives:

| MONTH | START_DATE | END_DATE | DAYS_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-08-01 | 2018-08-31 | 2018-10-05 | 1 |
| 2018-09-01 | 2018-08-31 | 2018-10-05 | 30 |
| 2018-10-01 | 2018-08-31 | 2018-10-05 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-02-04 | 7 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-02-04 | 4 |

And if you don't like the look for CTE's

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', dateadd('month', r.rn, d.start_date)) as month
    ,d.start_date
    ,d.end_date
    ,datediff('day', greatest(d.start_date, month), least(d.end_date, dateadd('day', -1, dateadd('month', 1, month))))+1 as days_count
FROM (
    SELECT 
        start_date
        ,end_date
        ,datediff('month', start_date, end_date) as m
    FROM data_table
) as d
JOIN (
    SELECT row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn
    FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000))
) as r ON r.rn <= d.m
ORDER BY d.start_date, month;
```

Comment: oh yes this works wonderfully! but can you explain what the purpose of large_range?

Comment: that is an array of rows, so when you join to it, to have all the intermediate values.. in prod you should just have a pre-existing table with more rows that you will ever have gap of days between start and end dates.

Comment: sorry I'm not sure I follow, how is it being used in the query, I see its being joined on pre_condition month but what does it do?

Comment: it provide a sequence of values [0,...,N] between the start month and end month, so we can add that offset to the start to endup with all the months.

Answer (score 1):

You should add another column to indicate the type of count you're calculating, but you can accomplish this with `datediff`,`last_day`, and `date_trunc`(to get first of month). Here is an example

```
set start_date='2022-01-25'::date;
set end_date='2022-02-04'::date;

select $start_date,
       $end_date,
       'Start_Remainder' as label,
       datediff(day,$start_date,last_day($start_date))+1 as days_count
union all
select $start_date,
       $end_date,
       'End_Accrued' as label,
       datediff(day,date_trunc('month',$end_date),$end_date)+1 as days_count
```

If I were you, I would have the counts in separate columns

```
select $start_date,
       $end_date,
       datediff(day,$start_date,last_day($start_date))+1 as Start_Remainder_Days,
       datediff(day,date_trunc('month',$end_date),$end_date)+1 as End_Accrued_Days
```

Comment: thanks for responding! but I'm seeing an error when I try this, I've added the error to my question

Comment: @KristiLuna Sorry, it was a missing comma. Try again please

Comment: no worries, I should have seen that too! but I'm not sure this the last one will work for instance if I have multiple months like if my start_date is 2022-01 and my end date is 2022-03-23.
And the first query doesn't seem to work as I had hoped, its showing me the total dates between start and end date, but its not showing how many days are in the month between that range

Comment: @KristiLuna Your updates to the question significantly alter the original problem statement.  I suggest you rollback the updates and ask a new question with the additional details. You may accept this answer if you honestly believe it solved your questions as it was originally intended.