# Taking Count Based On Year and Month from Date Columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to take count based on from and to  date. using from and to date I am trying to take year and month then based on month and year taking count. can someone suggest me how can i implement this.

```
Database : Snowflake
```

[image]

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Column from and to data type?

Comment: I am doing it in sql, datatype is Datetime for the columns. @jarlh D-Shih

Comment: There are dozens of SQL databases. Which one are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: Snowflake @jarlh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snowflake - given a start and end date column, break out each month and count number of days for the month into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591296/snowflake-given-a-start-and-end-date-column-break-out-each-month-and-count-nu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do more less the solution to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591296/snowflake-given-a-start-and-end-date-column-break-out-each-month-and-count-nu/71592629#71592629)

but here let me do all the work for you:

```
WITH data_table(start_date, end_date) as (
    SELECT * from values
        ('2022-01-15'::date, '2022-02-12'::date),
        ('2021-12-25'::date, '2022-03-18'::date),
        ('2022-02-25'::date, '2022-03-06'::date),
        ('2021-10-20'::date, '2022-01-07'::date)

), large_range as (
    SELECT row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn
    FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000))
), pre_condition as (
    SELECT 
        date_trunc('month', start_date) as month_start
        ,datediff('month', month_start, date_trunc('month', end_date)) as m
    FROM data_table
)
SELECT
    to_char(dateadd('month', r.rn, d.month_start),'MON-YY') as month_yr
    ,count(*) as count
FROM pre_condition as d
JOIN large_range as r ON r.rn <= d.m
GROUP BY 1;
```

| MONTH_YR | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| Jan-22 | 3 |
| Dec-21 | 2 |
| Feb-22 | 3 |
| Oct-21 | 1 |
| Nov-21 | 1 |
| Mar-22 | 2 |

Comment: Yes @Simeon Pilgrim it is more or less same. I want do it based on month and year basis and need to convert date in mon yyyy format